# How to throw an exception on another Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, future, guava

So I'm using `ListenableFuture` as a return type for certain operations. I expect the users to add callback to the future and then handle the success and exception cases. Now if the user cannot handle the exception, I want to have the ability to throw that exception onto the main Thread. Here's some code example:

```
public class SomeProcessor {

  ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

  public ListenableFuture<String> doStringProcessing() {
    return executor.submit(() -> doWork());
  }

  private String doWork() {
    return "stuff";
  }

}
```

Then in a client class:

```
public class SomeConsumer {

  public SomeConsumer (SomeProcessor processor) {
    Futures.addCallback(processor.doStringProcessing(), new FutureCallback<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(String result) {
        // do something with result
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        if (t instanceof ExceptionICanHandle) {
          // great, deal with it
        } else {
          // HERE I want to throw on the Main thread, not on the executor's thread
          // Assume somehow I can get a hold of the main thread object
          mainThread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(mainThread, t);
          // This above code seems wrong???
          throw new RuntimeException("Won't work as this is not on the mainthread");
        }
      }
    }, MoreExecutors.directionExecutor());
  }

}
```

Comment: Why does it matter which thread is running when you handle the exception? What does "throw on the Main thread" mean to you?

Comment: Basically I want the application to crash! If I just throw in the callback thread, it won't cause the application to crash.

Comment: You could call System.exit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this.<sup>1</sup>

Hence, this question boils down to a combination of 2 simple things:

- How do I communicate some data from a submitted task back to the code that is managing the pool itself? Which boils down to: How do I send data from one thread to another, and...
- How do I throw an exception - which is trivial - `throw x;`.

In other words, you make the exception in your task, and *do not `throw` it*, instead, you store the object in a place the main thread can see it, and notify the main thread they need to go fetch it and throw it. Your main thread waits for this notification and upon receiving it, fetches it, and throws it.

A submitted task cannot simply 'ask' for its pool or the thread that manages it. However, that is easy enough to solve: Simply *pass* either the 'main thread' itself, or more likely some third object that serves as common communication line between them, to the task itself, so that task knows where to go.

Here is one simplistic approach based on the raw synchronization primitives baked into java itself:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // I am the main thread
  // Fire up the executorservice here and submit tasks to it.
  // then ordinarily you would let this thread end or sleep.
  // instead...

  ExecutorService service = ...;
  AtomicReference<Throwable> err = new AtomicReference<>();
  Runnable task = () -> doWork(err);
  service.submit(task);
  while (true) {
    synchronized (err) {
      Throwable t = err.get();
      if (t != null) throw t;
      err.wait();
    }
  }
}

public void doWork(AtomicReference<Throwable> envelope) {
  try {
    doActualWork();
  catch (Throwable t) {
    synchronized (envelope) {
      envelope.set(t);
      envelope.notifyAll();
    }
  }
}
```

There are many, many ways to send messages from one thread to another and the above is a rather finicky, primitive form. It'll do fine if you don't currently have any comms channels already available to you. But, if you already have e.g. a message queue service or the like you should probably use that instead here.

[1] `Thread.stop(someThrowable)` literally does this as per its own documentation. However, it doesn't work - it's not just deprecated, it has been axed entirely; calling it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` on modern VMs (I think at this point 10 years worth of releases at least), and is marked deprecated with the rather ominous warning of *This method is inherently unsafe.* and a lot more to boot, it's not the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. So basically `mainThread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(mainThread, t);` doesn't work right?

Comment: No, that just asks the uncaught exception handler to do its thing, which is, unless you changed it, 'dump the data to syserr'. It doesn't throw anything. __There is no way__ to throw an exception in the middle of another thread - `Thread.stop` does precisely that, and it was so problematic, it has been retroactively removed from the JDK, which java never does. That just goes to show how utterly impossible it is to do that correctly.

Comment: Yeah so I was thinking if I change the main thread's uncaught exception handler to just throw ...

Comment: You're putting the cart before the horse. An exception that bubbles up all the way will 'kill' a thread by ending each method as it bubbles to the top. At the very end, it is sent to the uncaught exception handler. So, given that you do not seem to understand, let me write this out in bold, __sending an exception to the uncaught exception handler will print it to syserr and does absolutely NOTHING ELSE WHATSOEVER__. Replacing it would also accomplish __absolutely nothing useful__.

Comment: I get that it will just print it as the default handler. That's why I said if I replace it and in my replacement implementation, I simply `throw t;` right away. That would ensure that I threw it in the main thread right?

Comment: .... man, you just don't want to hear it, do you. No. Java itself invokes `main` (or `run()` when considering a Thread). It has, essentially: `public class Thread { public void start() { try { runnable.run(); } catch (Throwable t) { uncaughtHandler.handle(t); }}` - that is all. It is not magic.

Comment: I think we have arrived at the point that there's something in your head that is so enamoured with a wrong idea, you do not want to hear any retorts. Which, you know, happens. But, the solution is to go experiment and see why it won' work.